# String narrowed to String Literal type when passed to generic function alongside another typed function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following sample, I have a function which takes a generic type `V` as a parameter, alongside another function which also takes `V` as a parameter.

When I call the function with a string, and an anonymous function which infers the type of its parameter from the original function's signature, I get a result which is typed how I would expect: `string`.

However, when I call it with a separately declared function which conforms to the signature, the type of the string parameter is narrowed to a string literal.

```
type Placeholder<V> = (value: V) => void;

const myTestFunction = <V extends any>(
    value: V,
    placeholder: Placeholder<V>
) => {
    return value;
}

const aTypedFunction = (value: string) => { return };

// "isLiteralType"
const typedResult       = myTestFunction("isLiteralType", aTypedFunction);

// "string"
const inferredResult    = myTestFunction("isStringType", (value) => { return });
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwMYQBYHs4BMICcA8AagHxQC8UAFAG4JwCuEAXFIQJTmnXoCWWA3AChBSdADsAzsCgBbEABUIUgGL0xSYD3HkoRKBAAewCGKwSoCMSGKVBUe1FoNmrADR2HYRCgzY8LeGQ0TBwCEkEOMlIAbw97XAhgelwxRzpGIQBfYVFJaQR5cAgsVXVNbQoadJcpXB4xAHNImKgEpJSoTKERcSkoUEgsACUlejhpBwcKOUUVNQ0tMUoAIh4JABkeY1w6Qshl1ws94tKF8TZ+ScmAemuoVY2tvF2i5Z68qHqAMzwE4dHxpNpgolMBTuUlg8AMrAOqNY4HKhORjNKDRVqJZKpTIXey3e61eoNZZAA)

This seems to be due to the explicit typing of the `value` parameter in `aTypedFunction`, since explicitly typing the parameter in the anonymous function also produces a string literal result. I have no idea why this would be the case, however!

Why is this type narrowing happening, and how can I change either `myTestFunction` or `aTypedFunction` so that the former will accept the latter as an argument *without* narrowing the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters are generally inferred from one argument; for your function, `V` will be inferred from the parameter `value: V` because its type is the raw type parameter, so given an invocation of the function, the type `V` can be inferred very easily - just look at the type of the first argument in the invocation, and use that for `V`. That's what's happening here, and that's why `V` is inferred as `"isLiteralType"` in the invocation `myTestFunction("isLiteralType", aTypedFunction)`.

The same applies when you pass a typed arrow function directly. That said, I actually don't know why you get a different result with an un-typed arrow function. I'm as curious as you are about that.

Fortunately, we don't need to figure out why the second example behaves differently: armed with the knowledge that a type parameter will normally be inferred from whichever argument it's easier to infer it from, if we want the type parameter to be inferred from `placeholder` instead of `value`, make it `placeholder: P` instead of `value: V`. I've written a solution below, which derives the type of `value` from `P` rather than deriving the type of `placeholder` from `V`.

```
type Placeholder<V> = (value: V) => void;
type PlaceholderComponent<P extends Placeholder<any>> = P extends Placeholder<infer V> ? V : never

const myTestFunction = <P extends Placeholder<any>>(
    value: PlaceholderComponent<P>,
    placeholder: P
) => {
    return value;
}

const aTypedFunction = (value: string) => { return };

// string
const typedResult       = myTestFunction("isLiteralType", aTypedFunction);
```

Note also that the invocation with an untyped callback will result in `any` rather than `string`; this makes sense because a parameter without a type annotation has type `any` by default when its type can't be inferred from context.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwMYQBYHs4BMICcA8AagHxQC8UAFAG4JwCuEAXFIQJTmnXoCWWA3AChQkWIhQZseAMLoAtmHQA7CEuD4YUCAA9gqrAGcxyNJhwEESkMVIVNOvUsPGJZvPh5KAZnlakA-KxQLCrUeIKCSMoGwFByIAAqEDEAYvRKSMA8yuRQGlq6+kbwJpLm+JbWxJSCUHVQtAzMLqZSuLIKyqrqMMQANLX1YOKt5iwwghxkpADeg3W4EMD0uEoNdIxCAL4RUUoxUAgJ4BBYaRlZORQ0G80xuJ4A5lOzUIvLq1BbQoIA9L9Qe5PSLRWIiU4AJWS9DgsXq9Qo8SSqXSmWySkoACIeAYADI8PS4OjHSCYvqHEmnc5o5RsIRAA)

Comment: Thank you, this is great, although I've just realised my issue is a lot simpler than I thought and resolved by the first part of this answer. I'm used to strings only being literals when defined by `const` or as a property on some object, not passed inline as a parameter - the test case was the problem, not my real code. I do actually need passed functions to be able to infer their parameter type from `value`, so I don't think I can use this, but I'll be sure to remember this strategy in the future.